# Where is it written, "To oppress is a sin, but to tolerate oppression is a far greater sin"

Tags: gita

"To oppress is a sin, but to tolerate oppression is a far greater sin"

I always though this verse came from the Gita, but I do not see it anywhere. If this is not in the Gita, can someone tell me where this verse comes from?

Comment: Do a simple google search, has links to islamic scriptures.....

Comment: Obviously I used google before posting this question. Do you have any references?